# postgresql searching in an array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I've got an array which contains couples of tags : name, value.

I want to get the value of a specific tag name, so this sql works for me but I have to know where is my name :

`select "Tag_List"[2][2] from "table1" where "Tag_List"[2][1] = 'mytagname'`

How to do when I don't know where is 'mytagname'

Comment: A jsonb column would be a much better solution for key/value pairs

Comment: Sorry, the column is like that, cannot modify it...